# Vue3 problems with reactivity in depth when using the plugin i18n

Tags: typescript, internationalization, vuejs3, vuetify.js

In my project, I have integrated breadcrumb navigation. However, in order to make it more maintainable, I wanted to extract the individual breadcrumb items into a separate TypeScript file. As a consequence, the breadcrumb is no longer automatically translated when I switch languages.

breadcrumbUtils.ts:

```
import i18n from '@/plugins/i18n'
import { reactive } from 'vue'


export const breadcrumbs = reactive({
  companySelection: {
    title: i18n.global.t('BREADCRUMB.COMPANY_SELECTION'),
    to: { name: 'company-selection' }
  },
  competenceFields: {
    title: i18n.global.t('BREADCRUMB.COMPETENCE_FIELDS'),
    to: { name: 'landingpage' }
  }
})
```

router.ts:

```
import { type RouteMeta, type RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router'
import { breadcrumbs } from './breadcrumbUtils'

const homeRoutes: Array<RouteRecordRaw & { meta: RouteMeta }> = [
  {
    path: '/company/:company',
    name: 'landingpage',
    component: async () => await import('../views/LandingPage.view.vue'),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
      breadCrumb: [breadcrumbs.companySelection, breadcrumbs.competenceFields]
    }
  }
]

export default homeRoutes
```

breadcrumb-component.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-breadcrumbs :items="breadCrumbs">
    <template v-slot:divider>
      <v-icon size="small">mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
    </template>
  </v-breadcrumbs>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
// #region Imports
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
// #endregion

// #region CustomImports
// #endregion

// #region Props
// #endregion

// #region Data
// TODO: disable last element
const route = useRoute()

const breadCrumbs = computed(() => {
  try {
    if (route.meta.breadCrumb) {
      if (typeof route.meta.breadCrumb === 'function') {
        console.log('breadcrumb function', route.meta.breadCrumb(route))
        return route.meta.breadCrumb(route)
      }

      console.log('breadcrumb array', route.meta.breadCrumb)
      return route.meta.breadCrumb.map((item) => ({
        ...item,
        title: item.title
      }))
    }
    return []
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error('Error in breadCrumbs computation:', error.message)
    // ...
    return []
  }
})
// #endregion

// #region Emits
// #endregion

// #region Functions
// #endregion
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
// scss
</style>
```

I have tried this completely without using ref and reactive, both individually and in combination.